# How do you inner merge two dataframes with a tolerance value?

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.6

I have two dataframes:

```
 df1<-   A      C
       7.629    1
       5.227    2
       5.472    3
       5.386    4
       5.445    5

         A      B  
 df2<- 7.634   10.0
       7.732   30.0
       5.223   33.0
       5.479   22.0
       5.390   49.0
       5.439   53.0
```

I'd like to perform an inner merge on column A with a tolerance value of ±0.01 to get the resulting datafame:

```
df3<-       A       B      C 
          7.634   10.0     1
          5.223   33.0     2
          5.479   22.0     3
          5.390   49.0     4 
          5.439   53.0     5
```

Is this possible to do?

(note that column A of df3 has values copied from df2)

Comment: If my solution is worked after you updated the pandas, You can accept it :)

Comment: Hi Wen, I'm still having trouble getting it to work, sorry :/... I'm getting the error "Length of values does not match length of index" when using "loc"...

Comment: I'm using a different set of data from the example (which was made up for simplicity) where df2 has 72 rows, so there can be multiple values of column B associated to the 5 values in column A of df1... also, my error value is more like +/-0.003, so I can't use the first solution (I just used  ±0.01 for simplicity again) D:

Comment: For now, I've used:
v1 = df1[['A']].values
v2 = df2[['A']].values
dfx=df2[np.isclose(v2, v1[:, None], .003).any(0).any(1)]
and then used the first solution that you gave - which has done exactly what I would like to do for this dataset :)! It might not work for more complicated datasets that I plan on using in the future, but it will do for now! Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer ^^!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , I just have time look into your comments,Glad it help ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`merge_asof` seems solve your problem (Recommend 2nd method , I learn it from Zero~)

```
pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('A'), df1.sort_values('A'), direction='nearest',on='A').sort_values('C').drop_duplicates('C')
Out[415]: 
       A  C     B
0  5.227  2  33.0
1  5.386  4  49.0
2  5.445  5  53.0
3  5.472  3  22.0
4  7.629  1  10.0
```

Or using `IntervalIndex`

```
df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['A']-0.01,df2['A']+0.01,closed='both')
df1['B']=df2.loc[df1.A].B.values
df1['A']=df2.loc[df1.A].A.values
df1
Out[450]: 
                    A  C     B
[7.619, 7.639]  7.634  1  10.0
[5.217, 5.237]  5.223  2  33.0
[5.462, 5.482]  5.479  3  22.0
[5.376, 5.396]  5.390  4  49.0
[5.435, 5.455]  5.439  5  53.0
```

Comment: Values don't match OP's. You need `pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='A'), df1.sort_values(by='A'), direction='nearest').sort_values('C').drop_duplicates(subset=['C'])`

Comment: got it , fix it

Comment: Neat use of interval :)

Comment: Nice.  I like IntervaIndex usage here.  +1

Comment: I keep getting the error "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'IntervalIndex'" :/