# How to compare two data frames of different size based on a column?

Tags: python, r, pandas, comparison

I have two data frames with different size

df1

```
     YearDeci  Year  Month  Day  ...  Magnitude    Lat    Lon  
0     1551.997260  1551     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  74.50      
1     1661.997260  1661     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  75.00      
2     1720.535519  1720      7   15  ...        6.5  28.37  77.09      
3     1734.997260  1734     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  75.00      
4     1777.997260  1777     12   31  ...        7.7  34.00  75.00
```

and

df2

```
         YearDeci  Year  Month  Day  Hour  ...  Seconds   Mb     Lat     Lon  
0     1669.510753  1669      6    4     0  ...        0  NaN  33.400  73.200    
1     1720.535519  1720      7   15     0  ...        0  NaN  28.700  77.200    
2     1780.000000  1780      0    0     0  ...        0  NaN  35.000  77.000    
3     1803.388014  1803      5   22    15  ...        0  NaN  30.600  78.600    
4     1803.665753  1803      9    1     0  ...        0  NaN  30.300  78.800
5     1803.388014  1803      5   22    15  ...        0  NaN  30.600  78.600.
```

1.I wanted to compare df1 and df2 based on the column 'YearDeci'. and find out the common entries and unique entries(rows other than common rows).

2.output the common rows(with respect to df2) in df1  based on column 'YearDeci'.

3.output the unique rows(with respect to df2) in df1  based on column 'YearDeci'.

***NB: Difference in decimal values up to *+/-0.0001* in the 'YearDeci' is tolerable**

The expected output is like

row_common=

```
      YearDeci     Year   Month  Day ...   Mb     Lat     Lon 
2     1720.535519  1720      7   15  ...  6.5  28.37  77.09
```

row_unique=

```
      YearDeci  Year  Month  Day  ...  Magnitude    Lat    Lon  
0     1551.997260  1551     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  74.50      
1     1661.997260  1661     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  75.00           
3     1734.997260  1734     12   31  ...        7.5  34.00  75.00      
4     1777.997260  1777     12   31  ...        7.7  34.00  75.00
```

Comment: Maybe something with `merge_asof`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you inner merge two dataframes with a tolerance value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772781/how-do-you-inner-merge-two-dataframes-with-a-tolerance-value)

Comment: How large are the DataFrames?

Comment: df1
[9000 rows x 27 columns]
df2
[6000 rows x 11 columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare *df1.YearDeci* with *df2.YearDeci* on the "each with each"
principle.
To perform comparison use *np.isclose* function with the assumed absolute
tolerance.

The result is a *boolean* array:

- first index - index in *df1*,
- second index - index in *df2*.

Then, using *np.argwhere*, find indices of *True* values, i.e. indices
of "correlated" rows from *df1* and *df2* and create a DateFrame from them.

The code to perform the above operations is:

```
ind = pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(np.isclose(df1.YearDeci[:, np.newaxis],
    df2.YearDeci[np.newaxis, :], atol=0.0001, rtol=0)),
    columns=['ind1', 'ind2'])
```

Then, having pairs of indices pointing to "correlated" rows in both DataFrames,
perform the following merge:

```
result = ind.merge(df1, left_on='ind1', right_index=True)\
    .merge(df2, left_on='ind2', right_index=True, suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
```

The final step is to drop both "auxiliary index columns" (*ind1* and *ind2*):

```
result.drop(columns=['ind1', 'ind2'], inplace=True)
```

The result (divided into 2 parts) is:

```
    YearDeci_1  Year_1  Month_1  Day_1  Magnitude  Lat_1  Lon_1   YearDeci_2  \
0  1720.535519    1720        7     15        6.5  28.37  77.09  1720.535519   

   Year_2  Month_2  Day_2  Hour  Seconds  Mb  Lat_2  Lon_2  
0    1720        7     15     0        0 NaN   28.7   77.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am just curious that datacompy from the pandas could significantly reduce the complexity of this code?

Comment: Yes, usage of *Numpy* methods can sometimes significantly improve the execution speed.
I used here a trick based on *np.newaxis* and it allowed to use *Numpy* broadcasting, which runs much quicker than two "ordinary" nested loops, running over *YearDeci* columns in both DataFrames. So don't forget about *Numpy*, it has the potential to speed up your calculations.

Comment: What changes i should make in the first line of code (ind) to get the False values ie. uncorrelated rows from df1 and df2?

Comment: Add "~" (NOT orerator) before "np.isclose". The idea is to negate the array generated by this function. But then you will have a big number of such pairs of rows.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but just like you mentioned I end up with a big number of rows, I also needed to obtain the compliment of the two data frames too.Simple modification in your code won't get me there?

Comment: The term *compliment of the two data frames* is not clear to me. I think you should describe it more clearly, preferably as a new question. It is a bad habit to put initially a question and then add another questions.

Answer (score 1):

The indices of the common rows are already in the variable ind

So to find the unique entries, all we need to do is, drop the common rows from the df1 according to the indices in "ind"
So it is better to make another CSV file contain the common entries and read it to a variable.

```
df1_common = pd.read_csv("df1_common.csv")

df1_uniq = df1.drop(df1.index[ind.ind1])
```