# How to find duplicate rows in a dataframe with given tolerance based on a single/multiple column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, comparison

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615048/how-to-compare-two-data-frames-of-different-size-based-on-a-column/58632430#58632430) is a suggested solution for listing the duplicate values by comparing two dataframes based on a column value. How to do the same thing for finding the duplicate rows containing in a dataframe itself by considering the given tolerance and list it in a new dataframe?

```
df
         YearDeci  Year  Month  Day  Hour  ...  Seconds   Mb     Lat     Lon  
0     1669.510  1669      6    4     0  ...        0  NaN  33.400  73.200    
1     1720.535  1720      7   15     0  ...        0  NaN  28.700  77.200    
2     1780.000  1780      0    0     0  ...        0  NaN  35.000  77.000    
3     1669.511  1669      6    4     0  ...        0  NaN  33.400  73.200    
4     1803.665  1803      9    1     0  ...        0  NaN  30.300  78.800
5     1803.388  1803      5   22    15  ...        0  NaN  30.600  78.600.
```

If we looking for the duplicate rows based on `YearDeci` with a tolerance level of `0.002`

```
expected output

1669.510  1669      6    4     0  ...        0  NaN  33.400  73.200   3     
1669.511  1669      6    4     0  ...        0  NaN  33.400  73.200
```

Or Just its index

```
index1 index2
0      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First sort the dataframe by the column where you are looking for rows that are within `0.002` of each other.
2. Then, you can use `.diff()` to find the diference between rows and filter if `.diff() is < 0.002`. You will also have to get the other row above it with `.shift(-1)`:

---

```
df = df.sort_values('YearDeci')
s = df['YearDeci'].diff() < 0.002
df[s | s.shift(-1)]
Out[1]: 
   YearDeci  Year  Month  Day  Hour  ...  Seconds  Mb   Lat     Lon
0  1669.510  1669      6    4     0  ...        0 NaN  33.4  73.200
3  1669.511  1669      6    4     0  ...        0 NaN  33.4  73.200
```

To get the index values:

```
df[(s | s.shift(-1))].index.tolist()
# OR [*df[(s | s.shift(-1))].index]

[0, 3]
```